# ¿Cómo puedo leer un numero cualquiera y luego imprimir todos los numero pares anteriores al mismo?

Tags: python

No me sale imprimir los números pares previos al ingresado ¿cómo debería hacerlo?

```
A=int(input("Ingresar un numero:"))
paso_intermedio=A%2
A=A-2
while paso_intermedio==0:
    print(A)
    A=A-2
```

Cuando lo hago de esta manera me pone números negativos.

Comment: Ya que la variable `paso_intermedio` no es modificada dentro del bucle, o bien es falsa ya de mano (y el bucle no se ejecuta), o bien es cierta siempre y tienes un bucle infinito. Dependerá de si A es par (no se ejecuta) o impar (bucle infinito). Entiendo que la condición debería ser `A>0`, y el paso intermedio servirte para restárselo inicialmente a `A` para asaegurarte de que empiezas por un par.

Answer (score 0):

Una versión un poco más rápida es comprobar primero si el número es impar. Si al número Le restas el numero%2, obtienes el primer par:

```
temp = n - (n % 2);
```

Ahora tienes el temp como el primer par, y podemos decrementar en pasos de 2:

```
For(; temp>= 2; temp-=2)
  System.out.println("numero par" + temp) ;
```

Comment: Es una pregunta de Python!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un bucle o bien, usar las *itertools*::

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

n = int(input("Ingresar un numero:"))
# Construimos un iterador que devuelve los pares menores
pares_menores = takewhile(lambda e: e<n, (2*i for i in count()))

# Hacemos lo que nos apetezca con los números.
# Si lo que quieres es imprimir:
for p in pares_menores:
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una forma rápida y simple:

```
num =int(input("Ingresar un numero:"))
print("El numero es " + str(num))
print("Los pares anteriores son: ")
if (num % 2) == 0:
    while num > 0:
        num = num - 2
        print(num)
else:
    num = num - 1
    print(num)
    while num > 0:
        num = num - 2
        print(num)
```